# Models connection thorough Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have model User in Postgres. Each user has Skills (Skill is also an existing model).
There are 2 categories of skills: known and learning.
What relations should I use to have possibility take both Known and Learning skills?

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the SQL schema.

Comment: I'm quite new to SQL, so I don't know what schema you are talking about, sorry (

Comment: SOmething like this: https://imgur.com/PymOo8J

Comment: You already have relations between both *known_skills* and *learning_skills* to *users* via the `known_skills.user_id` -> `users.id` and `learning_skills.user_id` -> `users.id`.  What are you looking for?  An example of SQL using these relations? Something else?

Comment: Ok, thank you for checking. I just wanted make sure that everything is good with relations. Another issue is to JOIN tables using seqeulize.